# Google autocomplete Address Form with <select> tag

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, google-geolocation

I trying to make web form with autocomplete fileds and i using code from these example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform?hl=ru

With  tag all works fine. But if i assign parameter 'country' to  tag by adding ID country i get nothing then - blank field.

So how can i get autocomplite data to  tag instead  tag?

There is my select tag

```
<select id="country">
<option value="" disabled selected>Country</option>
<option value="Romania">Romania</option>
<option value="Russia">Russia</option>
<option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
</select>
```

and there is my google init code part:

```
  var componentForm = {
      street_number: 'short_name',
      route: 'long_name',
      locality: 'long_name',
      administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
      country: 'long_name',
      postal_code: 'short_name'
    };
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with getting country component from the google places autocomplete. Your component form helps you here to select either short or long name from the data returned by google places library.

```
 var country = place.address_components[i][componentForm['country']];
```

Now you need to get the value of your select dropdown by country name found in the line of code above.

```
var val = $("#country option:contains('" + country + "')").val();
```

All that's left is to assign a select value to the found value:

```
$("#country").value = val;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.